# it was not found in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I have this code for deleted data from MSSQL database.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteData(PartnerStudy partner)
    {
        var partnerStudy = GetByID(partner.Idetity);
        DomainRepository repository = new DomainRepository();
        repository.Delete(partnerStudy);
        repository.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ShowData");
    }

    public PartnerStudy GetByID(int id)
    {
        DomainRepository repository = new DomainRepository();
        //PartnerStudy partner = repository.GetItem<PartnerStudy>(id);

        var partner = repository.GetItem<PartnerStudy>(id);
        repository.Dispose();
        return partner;

    }
```

In `DomainRepository` have this

```
public void Delete<T>(T item) where T : class, IEntity
{
    Set<T>().Remove(item);
}
```

here I have a problem.
If I try to delete have a error in line `Set<T>().Remove(item)`;

> {"The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the
>   ObjectStateManager."}

What does mean ?
Why not found and where is `ObjectStateManager` ?
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the repository variable as a parameter to the GetByID() method, and use the same repository for getting and deleting the item.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteData(PartnerStudy partner)
{
    using(var repository = new DomainRepository())
    {
        var partnerStudy = GetByID(partner.Idetity, repository);
        repository.Delete(partnerStudy);
        repository.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ShowData");
}

private PartnerStudy GetByID(int id, DomainRepository repository)
{
    var partner = repository.GetItem<PartnerStudy>(id);
    return partner;

}
```

I even added a using block, as it seems DomainRepository implements IDisposable.